# remove spaces and empty line in the end of a string vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, string

in vb.net i have a string that looks like this

```
"text text text                           
                             "
```

so in the end of it there are spaces and a new empty line

How can make this look like

```
"text text text"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string.TrimEnd`:

```
var s = @"text text text                           
                         ";
Console.Write(s.TrimEnd() + "<-- End"); // Output: text text text<-- End
```

`TrimEnd` trims from the end of the string, `Trim` removes from both the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: What if the first line is `text text text   `, and you want to keep those spaces on that line, but just remove the ending line with no text?  So the output should be `text text text   <-- End`

Comment: In that case it would be easier to `Split` via the newline: `var result = s.Split('\n')[0];`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `Trim()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that Trim() will cut the new lines too...if not you can use it with param - Trim('\n') or Trim('\t') for tabs or even specify a list of characters which you'd like to cut off.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim value As String = "text text text                           
                         "
Dim trimmed As String = value.Trim()
```

> Trim removes leading and trailing whitespace. String data often has
>   leading or trailing whitespace characters such as newlines, spaces or
>   tabs. These characters are usually not needed. With Trim we strip
>   these characters in a declarative way.

**Reference:** http://www.dotnetperls.com/trim-vbnet

Answer (score 1):

Use the `string.TrimEnd(params char[] trimChars)` method:

```
yourString.TrimEnd();
```